# Scoring in Code-Review gerrit category is not happening

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, sonar-gerrit

I have configured Sonar gerrit jenkins plugin which is initiated by gerrit trigger plugin through gerrit rest APIs.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit

I followed all the instructions mentioned and it working fine.

There is only one glitch i.e. the scoring for category "Code review" for my non interactive use is not happening.
i.e. the history of patch sets is saying that the user has scored for code review but under the code review category at the top right corner there is not entry for code review category.

May be not specific to sonar gerrit but a gerrit expert can help me here.

I hope i was able to explain the problem.

cheers,

Saurav

Comment: Could you post images of the History (expanded) and Votes sections?

Comment: Did you solved this ? How ?

Comment: I have answered my question, please check below

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding a category in the project.config of gerrit project. Please check below. The values you can change according to your need.

```
label "Sonar-Verified"]
    branch = refs/heads/*
    function = MaxWithBlock
    value = -2 Fails
    value = -1
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Verified
    defaultValue = 0
```

Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Code-Review category is used by Sonar-Gerrit plugin by default, so it can override/be overridden by score given by other users or Gerrit Trigger. It is strongly recommended to configure a separate label in Gerrit.

```
[label "Sonar-Verified"]
    function = MaxWithBlock
    value = -1 Issues found
    value =  0 No score
    value = +1 Verified
    defaultValue = 0
```

Don't forget to set up access rights:

```
[access "refs/heads/*"]
    label-Sonar-Verified = -1..+1 group Non-Interactive Users
```

When the specific for the plugin label is configured, it is possible to use it in Sonar-Gerrit plugin settings.

See [Plugin Wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+Gerrit#SonarGerrit-Pluginsettings) Gerrit Settings section for more details.